# Android ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation doesn't seem to exist

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions

Android L introduced a new animations feature: animating between similar Views in different activities. It's documented [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/animations.html).

I've tried to use `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation`, but it doesn't seem to be visible in the SDK (or in the jar at all), so I tried using reflection, and it returns a null value.

Has anyone else got it working?

Comment: Say, does the support library have this cool feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I got it working.

It seems like setting the value in styles.xml is completely ignored for now.

You'll need to do this in each Activity's onCreate till that's fixed

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
Transition transition = // load transition here.
getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(transition);
```

As per the same bug ViewAnimationUtils has, you'll see errors in Android Studio, it'll compile and run fine though.

Comment: Yeah it's a bug that android-l components are shown in android studio as errors but run without any problem. I created an issue for that & they already fixed it yesterday. They will bring an update soon :)

Comment: Can u please share the code for loading the transition..? I can't find a full code example of shared element transitions done in activity..

Comment: How can you make it work with Listview ? @MohammadAG

Comment: @Sandra TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(R.transition.your_transition));

Answer (score 5):

We can got it working with theme config for v21. 
Put these items into res/values-v21/styles.xml

```
 <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
```

Comment: In which file did you define the above values?  res/values/styles.xml? or res/values-v21/styles.xml? or somewhere else?

Comment: res/values-v21/styles.xml

Comment: the third one is meant to be: `<item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>`

Answer (score 2):

Here is something work with 5.0 sdk got after 10/17/14.

But not sure what is the expected behavior if enable window content transitions and called `setEnterTransition`/`setExitTransition` in both `mainActivity` and `secondActivity`. If they are different (e.g one choose Explode and other choose Slide), which one would be applied?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /*
        To enable window content transitions in your code instead, call the Window.requestFeature() method:
         */
        getWindow().requestFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        Transition ts = new Explode();  //Slide(); //Explode();

        ts.setStartDelay(2000);
        ts.setDuration(5000);

        /*
        If you have set an enter transition for the second activity,
        the transition is also activated when the activity starts.
         */

        getWindow().setEnterTransition(ts);
        getWindow().setExitTransition(ts);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_view);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, mainViewFragment.newInstance())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public void launchSecondActivity() {

            /*
            If you enable transitions and set an exit transition for an activity,
            the transition is activated when you launch another activity as follows:
             */

            Intent listIntent = new Intent(this, secondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());

        }

}
```

//===

```
public class secondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ///
        getWindow().requestFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        Transition ts = new Slide();  //Slide(); //Explode();

        ts.setDuration(3000);

        getWindow().setEnterTransition(ts);
        getWindow().setExitTransition(ts);

        ///

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scene_transition);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```